# Getting Permission denied when accessing consul with python

Tags: python, consul

While trying to debug [patroni](https://patroni.readthedocs.io) connection to consul, I tried to write simple python connector to consul myself.

That's what I'm doing(python3, Centos7)

```
import consul
c = consul.Consul(host='consul-host',port=port,token='some-token')
c.kv.get('/v1/kv/some/long/path/bar')
```

That's what I'm getting(same error as patroni produces):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/consul/base.py", line 554, in get
    params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/consul/std.py", line 22, in get
    self.session.get(uri, verify=self.verify, cert=self.cert)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/consul/base.py", line 223, in cb
    CB._status(response, allow_404=allow_404)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/consul/base.py", line 181, in _status
    raise ACLPermissionDenied(response.body)
consul.base.ACLPermissionDenied: rpc error making call: Permission denied
```

Curl works fine with that token.

```
curl --header "X-Consul-Token:some-token" http://consul-host:port/v1/kv/some/long/path/bar | jq .

[
  {
    "LockIndex": 0,
    "Key": "/v1/kv/some/long/path/bar",
    "Flags": 0,
    "Value": "Zm9v",
    "CreateIndex": 2951475,
    "ModifyIndex": 2951475
  }
]
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback is pointing to [consul/base.py:554](https://github.com/cablehead/python-consul/blob/master/consul/base.py#L554):

```
return self.agent.http.get(
    CB.json(index=True, decode=decode, one=one),
    '/v1/kv/%s' % key,
    params=params)
```

Since you're passing key `'/v1/kv/some/long/path/bar'` it will hit endpoint http://consul-host:port/v1/kv/v1/kv/some/long/path/bar and not http://consul-host:port/v1/kv/some/long/path/bar